# '[self theArray] =' instead of 'NSArray *theArray ='

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

If I wanted to create a 2x2 array, I would do:

```
NSArray *theArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String1",@"String2",nil],
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String3",@"String4",nil],
nil];
```

But if I wanted to create it in another way I get an error "Expression is not assignable"

```
[self theArray] = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String1",@"String2",nil],
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String3",@"String4",nil],
nil];
```

What would be the correct way to use my [self theArray] in the example above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
self.theArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...
```

`[self theArray]` is an accessor, not a mutator

or you can use

```
[self setTheArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];
```

Answer (score 5):

Property assignment is done using the dot notation. To keep is short use the `NSArray` literal syntax.

```
self.theArray = @[
    @[@"String1", @"String2"],
    @[@"String3", @"String4"]
];
```

This assumes you declared `theArray` as a property of course and a setter is available:

```
@property(strong) NSArray *theArray;
```

Comment: Property assignment is not necessarily done using the dot as the dot is just a convenience.